# MySQL subquery not returning correlating results

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a database for a real estate system, and I'm trying to produce a results set that contains the highest listing price out of all the listings for each office in the system. It's returning the correct highest listing price correlated with the correct offices, but the addresses/cities/states do not correlate with the highest listing price result.

Here's my SQL:

```
SELECT o.office_name, l.address, l.city, l.state, (SELECT MAX(l.listing_price)) AS highest_listing_price
FROM offices o
    JOIN agent_assignments aa
        ON o.office_key = aa.office_key
    JOIN client_listings cl
        ON aa.assignment_key = cl.assignment_key
    JOIN listings l
        ON cl.listing_key = l.listing_key
GROUP BY o.office_name;
```

Here's the result it gives:

```
+---------------------+------------------+--------------+-------+-----------------------+
| office_name         | address          | city         | state | highest_listing_price |
+---------------------+------------------+--------------+-------+-----------------------+
| Seqouia Real Estate | 838 Plum Rd      | Jasper       | IL    |             679000.00 |
| Mirage Property     | NULL             | Orchardville | IN    |             739000.00 |
| Excelsior Estates   | NULL             | Sandlake     | IL    |             605300.00 |
| Silverwood Realty   | 399 Apricot Ave  | Roseville    | IL    |             475000.00 |
| Hearthstone Nooks   | 290 Highridge Dr | Roseville    | IL    |             925000.00 |
+---------------------+------------------+--------------+-------+-----------------------+
```

And here is the information from the tables I'm using for this query:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS offices;
CREATE TABLE offices
(
    office_key      INT     PRIMARY KEY,
    office_name     VARCHAR(50),
    address         VARCHAR(50),
    city            VARCHAR(30),
    state           CHAR(2),
    zip_code        VARCHAR(10),
    phone_number        VARCHAR(10),
    fax_number      VARCHAR(10),
    email_address       VARCHAR(50),
    remarks         VARCHAR(1000)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS agent_assignments;
CREATE TABLE agent_assignments
(
    assignment_key      INT     PRIMARY KEY,
    agent_key       INT     REFERENCES agents (agent_key),
    office_key      INT     REFERENCES offices (office_key),
    office_manager_flag CHAR(1),
    date_assigned       DATE,
    end_date        DATE
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS listings;
CREATE TABLE listings
(
    listing_key     INT     PRIMARY KEY,
    listing_status      INT     REFERENCES listing_status (listing_status_key),
    listing_type        INT     REFERENCES listing_types (listing_type_key),
    date_listed     DATE,
    date_expires        DATE,
    date_unlisted       DATE,
    reason_unlisted     INT     REFERENCES unlisted_reasons (unlisted_reason_key),
    address         VARCHAR(50),
    city            VARCHAR(30),
    state           CHAR(2),
    zip_code        VARCHAR(10),
    lot_number      VARCHAR(50),
    residential_area    INT     REFERENCES residential_areas (residential_area_key),
    listing_price       DECIMAL(13, 2),
    listing_agreement_signed_date       CHAR(1),
    remarks         VARCHAR(1000)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS client_listings;
CREATE TABLE client_listings
(
    client_listing_key  INT     PRIMARY KEY,
    listing_key     INT     REFERENCES listings (listing_key),
    assignment_key      INT     REFERENCES agent_assignments (assignment_key),
    client_key      INT     REFERENCES clients (client_key)
);
```

One thing I tried was using this to correlate the address, but it resulted in an error "subquery returns more than one row":

```
WHERE l.address = (SELECT l.address FROM listings l WHERE l.listing_price = (SELECT MAX(l.listing_price)))
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the table definitions. Are you able to provide sample data as well as what your expected output is? It's hard to know what's wrong with the output you've provided when the desired output is not known!

Comment: A result set with no corresponding data set is about as much fun as a stick without a lollipop

Answer (score 1):

You need to identify record with max listing price first and then get all the required columns. Your query is identifying only max of listing price and not other columns associated with it.

Try this:

```
set @rownum := 0;

select * from (SELECT o.office_name, l.address, l.city, l.state, l.listing_price, (@rownum := @rownum + 1) AS rn
FROM offices o
    JOIN agent_assignments aa
        ON o.office_key = aa.office_key
    JOIN client_listings cl
        ON aa.assignment_key = cl.assignment_key
    JOIN listings l
        ON cl.listing_key = l.listing_key
order by l.listing_price desc)
where rn=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM (SELECT o.office_name, l.address, l.city, l.state, 
             l.listing_price AS highest_listing_price
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY o.office_name ORDER BY l.listing_price DESC) as seqnum
      FROM offices o JOIN
           agent_assignments aa
           ON o.office_key = aa.office_key JOIN
           client_listings cl
           ON aa.assignment_key = cl.assignment_key JOIN
           listings l
           ON cl.listing_key = l.listing_key
      ) o
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```